# Flutter Drift package | Can you define queries in a separate file?

Tags: flutter, flutter-moor

...or better yet, define them in various places like each entity's Model or Repository.

My goal is to keep my database.dart file from becoming miles long because of ~6 CRUD functions per domain model, plus this also just fits the modular approach more IMO.
I may just be missing an obvious pattern or something. Somewhat new to Flutter so please point me in the right direction.

Ta

I already have my Tables registered in separate files, so looking for something similar for Queries.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using DAOs in drift, [view here](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/advanced-features/daos/).

More details regarding the solution:

1. Create a file for the queries. For example `queries.dart`:

```
// file name: queries.dart
part 'queries.g.dart';

@DriftAccessor(tables: [Users]) // the tables used
class UsersDao extends DatabaseAccessor<AppDatabase> with _$UsersDaoMixin {

  UsersDao(super.db);

  // all your queries will go here
  Future<List<User>> getUsers() async { // sample query FYR
    return await select(users).get();
  }
}
```

**Note**: Make sure that the file name and the name provided in `part` matches. In this case `queries.dart` matches with `part 'queries.g.dart'`.

2. Make sure to change the annotation in the database file. For example `database.dart`:

```
// file name: database.dart
part 'database.g.dart';

@DriftDatabase(
  tables: [
    Users,
  ],
  daos: [
    UsersDao,
  ], // add this
)
class AppDatabase extends _$AppDatabase {
   // fill your code here, left blank intentionally
}
```

3. Re-run the code generation using the either of the commands:

- `dart run build_runner build` : generates all the required code once.
- `dart run build_runner watch` : watches for changes in your sources and generates code with incremental rebuilds. This is suitable for development sessions.

**Bonus**:
You can also write SQL queries along with table schemas in `.drift` files and map them to methods and call it like the same, [view here](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/sql-api/drift_files/)